# Sql Server Splitting column value into email and name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql.  I need help with separating 2 values from a column value.

Example column value:

```
Sam Taylor <Sam.Taylor@gmail.com>
```

I need 2 columns from that column.

```
Name         Email
Sam Taylor   Sam.Taylor@gmail.com
```

TIA

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/beu4tdDo4WFAwKXtt9KL8A/0

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, postgresql, oracle...? String functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: which DBMS you r using?

Comment: SQL Server Management studio

Comment: This can help https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/

Comment: SSMS is a client tool, not a database. You shouldn't be storing such data in the database anyway, this violates the most basic design rule, the 1st Normal Form. One field should only contain one thing

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @yourField nvarchar(100)='Sam Taylor <Sam.Taylor@gmail.com>'


SELECT  SUBSTRING (@yourField ,0,CHARINDEX('<',@yourField)) as Name,  SUBSTRING (@yourField ,CHARINDEX('<',@yourField)+1,CHARINDEX('>',@yourField)-CHARINDEX('<',@yourField)-1)  as Email
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this will be like below but assuming that you do not have < or > as data in name.

```
select datastring, 
        name=max(case when row=1 then value else null end),
        email=max(case when row=2 then value else null end)
    from
    (
    select
        datastring,
        value=REPLACE(value,'>',''),
        row=row_number() over (partition by datastring order by datastring)
    from yourtable 
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(datastring,'<')
    )t
    group by datastring
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT()` does not guarantee the ordering of the results.  So this method is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split()`, but like this:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when s.value not like '%@%>' then trim(s.value) end) as name,
             max(case when s.value like '%@%>' then replace(s.value, '>', '') end) as email             
      from string_split(t.full_email, '<') s
     ) v;
```

In older versions, you can use:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(left(full_email, charindex('<', full_email) - 1))) as name,
       replace(stuff(full_email, 1, charindex('<', full_email), ''), '>', '') as name
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8b0b7cd243a0cc4eea1c5a5c5953c2c) is a db<>fiddle.